# How I can add a title or a label above the section in contextMenu

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to add a label or a title in the context menu like this example

I tried to add Text and labels, but it appears as a menu item, not a label or a title

[image]

Comment: still unsolved right?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap Buttons with Section like that:

```swift
.contextMenu {
    Section("Primary Actions") {
        Button("First") {}
        Button("Second") {}
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add the header modifier to `Section` within a `List` view to achieve what you're asking as such:

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Header")) {
       Text("Example 1")
       Text("Example 2")
       Text("Example 3")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I was asking about the context menu, not the lists! O_o